# How to reload an absolute div in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I think there are lots of related questions on this but I could not find  an answer that can satisfy my question.

Suppose I have a `div` that has an absolute position and can only show when an element was clicked and that div will contain anything, I mean values from the database for example and when the user deletes a data on that div, the div will be automatically refreshed and updates the data on it.

My problem is that how could I refresh that div without refreshing the whole document(window). I know `window.reload` but that refreshes the entire document. How could this be done in jQuery.

Comment: Have you tried AJAX to get the data from external source and put it to that div? More information at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Ajax:

```
$.get('url_to_update_from',function(data){
$('.divToUpdate').html(data);
}).fail(function() { console.log("error - failed to get resouce"); });
```

Straight from [official docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

Comment: @Nesmar you can also do a .replaceWith(), this will place the new content in place of the element you are targeting, it's a slighty different behavior than .html(), but is sometimes useful.